# Placing Furniture on drag in AR Core

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I am new to ARCore in Unity. My colleague has already made this app on iOS. But I am having some problems dragging the object around and set it on a position. Also you can rotate it with 2 fingers. Here I am giving the ARKit equivalent code of m dragging. Can anyone help me with doing the same on AR Core

```
switch (Input.touchCount) {
  case 1:
    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
      var screenPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(touch.position);
      ARPoint point = new ARPoint {
        x = screenPosition.x,
        y = screenPosition.y
      };

      // prioritize reults types
      ARHitTestResultType[] resultTypes = {
        //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent, 
        // if you want to use infinite planes use this:
        ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlane,
        ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeHorizontalPlane, 
        ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeFeaturePoint
      };

      foreach (ARHitTestResultType resultType in resultTypes) {
        if (HitTestWithResultType(point, resultType)) {
          return;
        }
      }
    }
    break;

  case 2:
    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
      Vector2 direction = touch.deltaPosition;

      float yAngleIncrementVal = touch.deltaPosition.magnitude;
      Vector3 currentRotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

      if (direction.x > 0) {
        currentRotation.y += (yAngleIncrementVal * rotationScale);
      }
      else {
        currentRotation.y -= (yAngleIncrementVal * rotationScale);
      }

      transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation);
    }

    break;
  }
}
```

This script will attached to the gameobject which will move across the plane. How can I drag a gameobject and update the anchors so that it stays on the plane. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty much doing the same thing, and this is a simplified version of my own code:

```
case 1:
    if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        touchOffset = ARCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.position) - new Vector3(Input.GetTouch(0).position.x, Input.GetTouch(0).position.y, 0);
    }

    RaycastHit hit;
    LayerMask layers = (1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer(layersOfGroundObjects))
    Ray ray = ARCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position + new Vector2(mouseOffset.x, mouseOffset.y));
    if (!ClickedOnUI && Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layers))
    {
        if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            touchOffset = hit.point - gameObject.position;
        }

        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            gameObject.position = hit.point - touchOffset ;
        }
    }
case 2:
    float currentTouchDistance = Vector2.Distance(touches[0].position, touches[1].position);
    float diff_y = touches[0].position.y - touches[1].position.y;
    float diff_x = touches[0].position.x - touches[1].position.x;
    float currentTouchAngle = Mathf.Atan2(diff_y, diff_x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    if (isFirstFrameWithTwoTouches)
    {
        cachedTouchDistance = currentTouchDistance;
        cachedTouchAngle = currentTouchAngle;
        isFirstFrameWithTwoTouches = false;
    }

    float angleDelta = currentTouchAngle - cachedTouchAngle;
    float scaleMultiplier = (currentTouchDistance / cachedTouchDistance);
    float scaleAmount = cachedAugmentationScale * scaleMultiplier;
    float scaleAmountClamped = Mathf.Clamp(scaleAmount, scaleRangeMin, scaleRangeMax);

    if (enableRotation)
    {
        gameObject.localEulerAngles = cachedAugmentationRotation - new Vector3(0, angleDelta * 3f, 0);
    }
    if (enableRotation && enableScaling)
    {
        gameObject.localScale = new Vector3(scaleAmountClamped, scaleAmountClamped, scaleAmountClamped);
    }
```

I also use a touchOffset which is the distance away from the object's pivot (position) that the user has clicked to start dragging. I apply that offset to the final position every time it is dragged. It makes dragging feels much more natural. I also use it for a lot more in my own code, therefore it was quite important for me, but that is irrelevant for this question so I removed the rest of the code.

Moreover, I use many layers for what is considered ground, because I can put my furniture on more surfaces other than the ARCore tracked plane. If you only care about the tracked plane then either assign a layer to it, or use ARCore's raycast instead of Unity's one. Or just use my [Eazy ARCore Interface](https://github.com/VR-House/Eazy-ARCore-Interface) plugin that can do both (uses layers for tracked planes and makes things easier with raycasting for multiple surfaces)

Comment: Thank You I will let you know the resut once I fininsh implementing it

Comment: Can I get only 1 plane to detect? I just want ground. Not Any other surface

Comment: You mean the tracked plane detected with ARCore? Yes of course. You can either manually set a layer to it, or use [ARCore raycasting](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/unity/class/GoogleARCore/Frame#classGoogleARCore_1_1Frame_1a817348b6a702cc12c80f9078f52704d0). If you are using Eazy ARCore interface, then for layers, use this:
`LayerMask layers = 1 << EazyARCoreInterface.TrackedPlaneLayer;`

Comment: ARCore detects multiple layers on the I just want it to detect ground not anything else

Comment: ARCore will detect all horizontal planes. If you want to exlude planes detected on a table for example and take only the ones on the actual ground, you have to write your own logic for that. ARCore cannot distinguish between them automatically. However, I am not really sure how can you achieve something like that since there are not enough available data. Maybe you could always take the plane with the lowest y value, only if you know beforehand that anything that is going to get scanned will not be below the actual ground

Comment: Of course allow for some small threshold if you do that, since sometimes ARCore will detect a few different layers of planes on the same position before deciding to merge them into one